# Проверка уникальности группы статей в БД

Tags: php

Здравствуйте уважаемые программисты!

Ситуация такая: есть 100 статей в БД MySql на одну тематику, проверяю все статьи в сервисах проверки на уникальность - везде 100% уник, но когда сам просматриваю статьи вижу, что статьях есть повторяющиеся блоки... т.е. между собой статьи не уникальны.

Нужно решение на PHP как проверить на уник. статьи между собой.
Подскажите готовый класс для этих целей, если сталкивались...

Comment: Можно написать, в чем проблема.

 - придумываем способ разбивки статьи на блоки, например абзацами.
 - для каждого абзаца считаем хеш, к примеру md5\sha1
 - помещаем все хеши в какой нибудь map, находим дубликаты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Навскидку, чтобы не воротить что-то сложное, поищите готовые решения (на [github, запрос "diff"](https://github.com/search?l=PHP&q=diff)). Наверняка некоторые из них можно использовать для вашей задачи. Найдите библиотеку, которая позволяет настроить точность (символ, слово, предложение, абзац) и которая выдает разницу в каком-нибудь числовом эквиваленте (расстояние Левенштейна или что-нибудь побыстрее). Поиграйтесь с параметрами - получите нужный результат.